# Ошибка при тестировании AdMob

Tags: android, android-service, admob

Добавляю баннер. Пробую произвести тестовый показ на устройстве, выдает ошибку:

```
06-09 13:51:07.358  20865-20865/com.two_two.offshoreview E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.two_two.offshoreview, PID: 20865
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.two_two.offshoreview/com.two_two.offshoreview.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference
        at com.two_two.offshoreview.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
```

Вот сам исходный код:
Java:

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    AdRequest adRequest =new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice(getResources().getString(R.string.idEmulator)).build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

XML:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/idAdMob"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

Или должно пройти какое то время для активации "Идентификатор рекламного блока"?

Comment: А NullPointerException у вас на какой конкретно строчке всплывает?

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ вот на этой `adView.loadAd(adRequest);`

Comment: Эм-м-м... А вы точно в коде той активити, в разметке коей поместили XML баннера, ищете этот баннер?.. 0_о Так-то всё, вроде, верно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ случайно был удален `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` но теперь новая ошибка `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called.
            at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzy.zzcO(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzy.zza(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(Unknown Source)` в той же строке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, что у вас пространство имён [правильно объявлено](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23980933/3212712):

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Также проверьте, хватает ли места баннеру на экране.

И проверьте правильность ID баннера в приложении и панели управления AdMob.

Comment: спасибо в разметке дело было. Приложение запускается но баннер не показывает) Но это уже другая история буду разбираться.